# How to click on icons in UncontrollableCollapse in reactstrap and not trigger collapse?

Tags: reactjs, accordion, reactstrap

I have an accordion, when you click on it the content drops, all works well, but the problem is, i have a delete and an add button, i want to click them and not trigger the accordion. How can i accomplish that? I use UncontrolledCollapse from reactstrap and it has a toggler which is an id of an element.

```
<ul>
  <li id={`toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    <a>
      Some Accordion
    </a>
    <div className="icons">
      <div>+</div>
      <div><TrashIcon /></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <UncontrolledCollapse
    className="children"
    toggler={`#toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    {menuItemChildren}
  </UncontrolledCollapse>
</ul>
```

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRKiI.png)

All of this grayish background is my `<li></li>` that has an id toggler that will toggle the UncontrolledCollapse that will show all the nested items.

I can achieve it by making only the `<a></a>`to have a toggle id, the problem is,  i want to click on spaces between the icons and have the content drop.
**So what i want is to only have icons act as a non-toggler**
I tried doing it by applying `z-index:100`  to `icons div` but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a good case to use the controlled collapse. This way you can control when to toggle the accordion. In my example below, pay attention to my usage of `stopPropagation`

```
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState(false);

const toggle = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

<ul>
  <li id={`toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`} onClick={toggle}>
    <a>
      Some Accordion
    </a>
    <div className="icons">
      <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}>+</div>
      <div onClick={e => e.stopPropagation()}><TrashIcon /></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <Collapse
    isOpen={isOpen}
    className="children"
    toggler={`#toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    Menu Item Children
  </Collapse>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer! just move toggler from the `li` tag to a div and give `position:absolute` to icons

I changed it from this to

```
<ul>
  <li id={`toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    <a>
      Some Accordion
    </a>
    <div className="icons">
      <div>+</div>
      <div><TrashIcon /></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <UncontrolledCollapse
    className="children"
    toggler={`#toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    {menuItemChildren}
  </UncontrolledCollapse>
</ul>
```

to this

```
<ul>
  <li style={{position:'relative''}}
  >
//Add div
<div id={`toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}>
    <a>
      Some Accordion
    </a>
</div>
//Add position:absolute
    <div className="icons" style={{position:'absolute', bottom:0, left:0}}>
      <div>+</div>
      <div><TrashIcon /></div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <UncontrolledCollapse
    className="children"
    toggler={`#toggle-catalog-item-${item.id}`}
  >
    {menuItemChildren}
  </UncontrolledCollapse>
</ul>
```