# Reactstrap Conditional Collapse by e.target

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, toggle, reactstrap

I'm trying to create a conditional collapse that prevents certain elements within the header from toggling the collapse. For example, I have a delete button within the toggle element, but I don't want it to activate the toggle.

I tried:

```
const handleToggle = (e, id) => {
    if(!e.target.classList.contains('remove-btn')) {
        if (isOpen === id) {
            setIsOpen('');
        } else {
            setIsOpen(id);
        }
    }
};
```

and also using the e.target.name:

```
if(e.target.name !== 'remove-btn') {<allow toggle>}
```

And this is the toggle within the return:

```
<ListGroupItem
    onClick={() => handleToggle(id)}>
    <Button
        className='remove-btn'
        name='remove-btn'
        onClick={() => handleDelete(id)}>
        &times;
    </Button>
    {name}
</ListGroupItem>

<Collapse>...</Collapse>
```

If I click anywhere on the ListGroupItem, it should toggle the collapse, *unless* I click on the delete Button, which should only run the handleDelete function, and not toggle the collapse.

I know that the delete is eventually going to remove the whole element anyway, but I also have an input that is toggling the collapse and I don't want it to. Thanks for helping me understand this!

I found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192834/how-to-click-on-icons-in-uncontrollablecollapse-in-reactstrap-and-not-trigger-co) with a two possible solutions, but I'm wondering if there is a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [95faf8e76605e973](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8680805/95faf8e76605e973)'s answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64192834/how-to-click-on-icons-in-uncontrollablecollapse-in-reactstrap-and-not-trigger-co) question, and simply added the e.stopPropagation() function to the appropriate onClicks.

```
<ListGroupItem
    onClick={() => handleToggle(id)}>
    <Button
        className='remove-btn'
        name='remove-btn'
        onClick={(e) => { 
            e.stopPropagation(); 
            handleDelete(id);
        }}>
        &times;
    </Button>
    {name}
</ListGroupItem>
```